# How to access GTKMM widgets from other file?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I have a simple gtk+ application made with gtkmm, and I want to change the content of the window when I press a button, and I want to put that code in a seperate file (changeTitle.cc). How do I access the "buttons" object from that file?

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "buttons.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
  "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

Buttons buttons;


return app->run(buttons);

}
```

buttons.h:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLE_BUTTONS_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLE_BUTTONS_H

#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>

class Buttons : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
Buttons();

virtual ~Buttons();

protected:
//Signal handlers:
void on_button_clicked();

//Child widgets:
Gtk::Button m_button;
Gtk::Box buttonBox;
};

#endif //GTKMM_EXAMPLE_BUTTONS_H
```

buttons.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "buttons.h"
#include "changeTitle.h"

Buttons::Buttons()
{
m_button.add_pixlabel("info.xpm", "click here");

set_title("Menu");
set_border_width(10);

m_button.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun(*this,
          &Buttons::on_button_clicked) );

add(buttonBox);

buttonBox.pack_start(m_button);

show_all_children();
}

Buttons::~Buttons()
{

}

void Buttons::on_button_clicked()
{
changeTitle();
}
```

changeTitle.h:

```
void changeTitle();
```

changeTitle.cc:

```
#include "changeTitle.h"

void changeTitle()
{
    buttons.set_title("new title");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This isn't specific to `gtkmm` at all.** I wonder if you would benefit from some simple, non-GUI examples to improve your grasp of object scope, before pulling complex libraries into the equation to muddy the waters.

## Problem

**Accessing `buttons` directly from anywhere except within `main()` cannot be done with your present architecture.** `buttons` is a local object scoped in `main()`. It is not available to any other function, never mind any other translation unit (basically, file) - by which I mean they can't just refer to it by name. If you want them to use it, you have to pass it to them, or otherwise relax its scope such that they can pull it... more on that next.

[ Indenting your code properly would probably help you grok things more visually, including the issue of scope. ]

## Solution

So, with `buttons` as with any other scoped object, you either need to **pass the object** to any function that uses it, put all such functions within a `class` and **make the object a member variable**, or - *perish the thought* - use a global variable.

**The simplest option is putting your 'change title' logic right in your `signal-clicked` handler, letting it access the *current* `this` instance of `Buttons`** (really `Window`s; confusing name you chose) - which, handily, is **the same one whose *actual* `Gtk::Button` emitted the click.** Is there a reason you left `changeTitle()` as a free function that attempts to refer to one particular, *other* instance of `Buttons`?

If you *could* do this, say you created multiple `Buttons`es  - let's call them A, B, and C - **clicking the button in *any* would call `changeTitle()` on a *different* `Buttons` instance** in `main()` ... which seems weird. You can split class member definitions across multiple source files, by the way, if you didn't know.

So, clearly, some redesign is required. Which of these options you chose depends on how you want your program and its data to be organised. If none of this is on the right track, then you'd need to explain what you want further.

And I'll say it: Don't use a global variable... *unless* you have a *very* good justification. There are some, but not many. They're not quite as bad as a lot of people make out, but due to the diagnostic and maintenance headaches they risk opening up, nor should you use one without a good justification; they should not be a first option.

## Unaffiliated gushing

Btw, I love `gtkmm`, can't promote it enough. It's a fantastic project with great steering, which I think is woefully unsung in the larger 'community'. But again, it's orthogonal to the basic issue here, which is simple object scoping.